# Uncaught TypeError: elem.getClientRects is not a function when using multiple select on MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

```
Uncaught TypeError: elem.getClientRects is not a function
    at F.fn.init.offset (jquery-3.2.1.js:9984)
    at init._position (kendo.all.js:25000)
    at init.open (kendo.all.js:24855)
    at init.open (kendo.all.js:31282)
    at init._wrapperMousedown (kendo.all.js:31186)
    at HTMLDivElement.proxy (jquery-3.2.1.js:496)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.js:5206)
    at HTMLDivElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.2.1.js:5014)
```

I was trying 2 ways such as HTML and MVC on http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/index

But it will display errors.
on MVC, added

```
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```

- Jquery version is 3.2.1

Comment: Looks like it might be an issue with kendo and jQuery 3. See [here](https://github.com/vanderlee/colorpicker/issues/132) and [here](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/1877)

Comment: what's  version it supports???

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I found a bug reported under the project on github but the discussion has been closed except for key people. I get the error when I mouseover a span element that triggers a tooltip. I'm hoping this comment may reach them to provide some insight.

Answer (score 2):

According the error, `elem` seems like a jQuery object.

jQuery objects don't have a `getClientRects` method, only native DOM nodes does, so you probably want to extract the underlying DOM node first, using `get()`

```
elem.get(0).getClientRects()
```

Comment: yes, error is display at elem.get(0).getClientRects() in jQuery

Answer (score 1):

You need the proper mix of `jquery` and `jquery-ui`.

The combo required to use the new jquery version 3 is:

```
https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.0.0.js
```

Migrate is also needed.